# Cobertura generates my reports for code coverage, but the coverage shows as 0%

Tags: ant, junit, cobertura

All of my reports get generated, but my coverage shows as 0%. I even created one dummy test to make sure it wasn't the way my tests were written, and it doesn't show for the one dummy class I'm covering. Here is my Ant build for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="My Project Name" default="run.cobertura" basedir=".">

    <description>My Description</description>

    <!-- target: init -->

    <target name="init">

        <!-- create properties and directory structure -->

        <property name="src.path" value="${basedir}/src" />
        <property name="lib.path" value="${basedir}/lib" />
        <property name="output.path" value="${basedir}/bin" />
        <property name="testcase-unit-only.path" value="${basedir}/testcase-unit-only" />
        <property name="testcase-unit-only.output.path" value="${basedir}/test-classes" />

        <property name="cobertura.lib.path" value="${basedir}/lib-cobertura" />
        <property name="cobertura.path" value="${basedir}/cobertura" />
        <property name="cobertura.output.path" value="${cobertura.path}/bin" />
        <property name="cobertura.reports.path" value="${cobertura.path}/reports" />
        <property name="cobertura.data.file" value="${cobertura.path}/cobertura.ser" />

        <delete dir="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}" />
        <delete dir="${cobertura.path}"/>

        <mkdir dir="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${cobertura.path}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${cobertura.output.path}"/>

        <!-- define classpath references -->

        <path id="cp.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="${lib.path}">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>

        <path id="cp.classes.path">
            <pathelement path="${output.path}" />
        </path>

        <path id="cp.classes.test.path">
            <pathelement path="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}" />
        </path>

        <path id="cp.lib.cobertura.path">
            <fileset dir="${cobertura.lib.path}">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>

        <path id="cp.all.path">
            <path refid="cp.lib.path"/>
            <path refid="cp.classes.path"/>
            <path refid="cp.lib.cobertura.path"/>
        </path>

    </target>

    <!-- target: run.cobertura-instrument -->

    <target name="run.cobertura-instrument">

        <taskdef classpathref="cp.lib.cobertura.path" resource="tasks.properties"/>

        <cobertura-instrument todir="${cobertura.output.path}" datafile="${cobertura.data.file}">
            <fileset dir="${output.path}">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </cobertura-instrument>

    </target>

    <!-- target: compile.classes -->

    <target name="compile.classes">

        <javac srcdir="${src.path}" destdir="${output.path}">
            <classpath refid="cp.lib.path"/>
        </javac>

    </target>

    <!-- target: compile.tests -->

    <target name="compile.tests">

        <javac srcdir="${testcase-unit-only.path}" destdir="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}">
            <classpath refid="cp.all.path"/>
        </javac>

    </target>

    <!-- target: run.junit -->

    <target name="run.junit">

        <junit fork="true" dir="${basedir}" failureProperty="test.failed">

            <classpath location="${cobertura.output.path}"/>
            <classpath location="${output.path}"/>

            <sysproperty key="net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile" file="${cobertura.data.file}" />

            <classpath refid="cp.lib.path"/>
            <classpath refid="cp.classes.test.path"/>
            <classpath refid="cp.lib.cobertura.path"/>

            <formatter type="xml" />
            <!-- <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/> -->

            <batchtest todir="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}" unless="testcase">
                <fileset dir="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}">
                    <include name="**/*UnitTest.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>

        </junit>

    </target>

    <!-- target: run.cobertura -->

    <target name="run.cobertura" depends="init,run.cobertura-instrument,compile.classes,compile.tests,run.junit">

        <cobertura-report srcdir="src" destdir="${cobertura.reports.path}" datafile="${cobertura.data.file}"/>

    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I notice is that in the depends list for the run.cobertura target you instrument the compiled classes *before* you compile them.  That might work if you run twice, assuming the compiled classes from the first run are not cleared down, but doesn't seem quite right.  On the first run if there are no instrumented classes, your report would be empty.

Comment: This was indeed part of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same ant build scripts. It worked on my local workstation, but didn't on jenkins server.
But server had jdk 7 and workstation jdk6. After changing jdk on jenkins server to jdk6, code coverage generates without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

you must set debug on when you compile java

```
<javac **debug="on"** srcdir="${testcase-unit-only.path}" destdir="${testcase-unit-only.output.path}">
```